# Does size make a difference?

Tags: pokemon-go

Does the XS/XL on weight/height of the Pokemon affect the game play in anyway or is it just for some variance in the game?

Answer (score 2):

The "Youngster" medal requires you to catch Rattata's of a certain size. I'm not sure it serves any other purpose besides maybe bragging rights.